# Indication that a comment has been deleted

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It's fairly common for someone to make a comment, someone to reply and then the initial commenter to delete their comment because they realised they made a mistake or something.

This can often lead to the second comment appearing to make no sense without the context the first one provided.

Would it perhaps be beneficial to leave a placeholder along the lines of `------Comment Deleted------` where the deleted comment was so that future visitors at least know that there used to be something there?

Comment: Just flag the remaining comment as obsolete so that it can also be removed. People should be doing this when they delete their initial comment but it doesn't always happen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Comments are "second-class citizens" on this site. They're intended to be temporary; we *expect* them to get deleted when they outlive their usefulness. If the second comment no longer makes sense, flag it as obsolete. That's what the obsolete flag is for.

In any case, your proposed feature wouldn't actually improve things. If the comment makes no sense without the context, it's not going to make more sense just because there's a placeholder.

On top of that, on many posts we would have a *lot* of these placeholders when long comment discussions get cleaned up. Nobody wants to see this:

```
------Comment Deleted------

See my edit. - Asker 1 hour ago

------Comment Deleted------

See my edit. - Asker 1 hour ago

------Comment Deleted------

See my edit. - Asker 1 hour ago

------Comment Deleted------

@Joe can you answer my question? - Asker 1 hour ago

------Comment Deleted------

See my edit. - Asker 1 hour ago

@Joe can you answer my question? - Asker 1 hour ago

------Comment Deleted------

That's not what I'm asking. - Asker 1 hour ago

------Comment Deleted------

Thanks, I'll look into that. - Asker 1 hour ago
```

100% of that is useless, and it all needs to go. Placeholders aren't necessary to reach that conclusion and just make the clutter even harder to read.

Comment: Ahh, I never realised that comments were designed to be transient on here. Fair point.